# Windows Key shortcuts - can't find documentation

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a Dell XPS 15 with Windows 10 Home, and use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd> shortcuts all the time.

When I hold down the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, a helper screen is displayed:

[image: Windows key helper overlay]

I have tried holding down the <kbd>Win</kbd> key on other Windows devices but nothing happens. I can't find any documentation for this functionality, and I have no idea how to enable/disable it.

Does anybody know what this feature is called? Is there any information on how to enable/disable on other devices?

Comment: Seems it's a software made from Dell, I can't find anything about it though.

Comment: That's what I thought @CaldeiraG, however I wasn't able to find any information from Dell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [**Windows Shortcut Guide**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/shortcut-guide), part of the [**Powertoys**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) set of utilities for power users. It is not pre-installed on Windows by default but rather part of an open-source project (ran by Microsoft) inspired by the Windows 95 era PowerToys project.

You can grab the latest release from the releases page on their GitHub page [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install). All of the utilities in Powertoys are optional; If you wish to you can disable all but the shortcut guide.

Comment: Thanks! I now remember installing this a while ago.

Comment: For those who want the information, but not the PowerToys, Microsoft documents keyboard shortcuts for Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10 [at their support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts).